# Error handling on a simple Print Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Apologies - Just trying to get to grips with simple VBA in an Excel I'm working on. I have just about the simplest macro there is associated with a control button:

```
Sub Printx()
    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrint).Show
End Sub
```

Which is fine for what I need it to do. I'm struggling with the error handling if I click cancel on the resultant dialogue box. Can't seem to get past the runtime 1004 error. 
I have tried several goto lines but still get the same runtime error. Can someone please point out where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
     Sub Printx()      
      Dim x As Variant
      x = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrint).Show
      If TypeName(x) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
      End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this quick response. I'd tried something very similar. Still getting 1004 error "Method 'Show' of object 'Dialog' failed".

Comment: Strange!!Can you just post an image of the dialogbox that is popping

Comment: Hi Neelish,
The Message says:
Run-time error '1004':

Method 'Show' of object 'Dialog' failed

Comment: I meant the Dialog box of xldialogprint.show not the error message

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add simple resume error handling before making the call:

```
Sub Printx()

    On Error Resume Next
    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrint).Show

End Sub
```